# Calling function on when user pressed back button on the native screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, native

I am trying to implement that when a user clicked a back button on the native screen then I need to call a function.

For Example:

**I created a chat app in which on pressing the start chat button user is redirected to the native screen and whenever the user pressed the back button on the native screen and is redirected to the flutter screen that time I need to call a specific function.**

[image]

**In this on pressing start chat user is redirected to the native screen and chat with the agent.**

[image]

**Then pressing the back button on the native screen the user is redirected to the flutter screen so I need to call a specific function whenever the user is redirected to the flutter screen. Please help me as soon as possible stack community.**

Comment: You are looking for a callback in flutter that is triggered when native back button is pressed? If yes, then WillPopScope() is the one you're looking for

Comment: No, I am not looking for the native back button but when the user presses the native screen app bar back button time I need to call function.

Answer (score 1):

Think you go from Screen 1 to Screen 2. You use the following code:

```
Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()),
)
```

So, when user presses the back button on Screen 2 and comes back to Screen one you want to reload api data, right? Just do the following in the above function:

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()),
                  ).then((value) {
                    callApiToReloadData();
                  });
```

So whenever user returns to Screen 1 from Screen 2 using Navigation.pop() or by pressing the appbar back button, **callApiToReloadData()** function will be called.

Comment: This does not work with the web back button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WillPopScope() and this video may help u

[Flutter Tutorial - Handle Back Button Pressed [2021] WillPopScope Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEmJLvL1pzQ&ab_channel=JohannesMilke)